# Strtol() function basic c

Tags: c, string, int, codeblocks

When I am using the `strtol()` function, when I am trying convert:

```
2015-08-12
```

I would like it to fail conversion rather than converting only `2015`?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", argc);


  int i = 1;
  while (argc > i)
  {

  char *p;
  int num;

  errno = 0;
  long conv = strtol(argv[i], &p, 10);

// Check for errors: e.g., the string does not represent an integer
// or the integer is larger than int
  if (errno != 0 || *p != '\0' || conv > INT_MAX)
    {
      printf("this is word:%s\n ",p);
      //printf("chyba");
    }
  else
    {
    // No error
    num = conv;
    printf("this is number: %d\n", num);
  }

    i = i + 1;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? That the output is "This is word -08-26"? In that case, just print `argv[i]` instead if `p`. The original pointer you passed in will be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `strol()` and the like convert the initial substring that matches.  If you were to call it again on the rest of the string, though, you would need to strip out the dashes, or they would be interpreted as minus signs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it appears that `strtol()` did not convert the text `2015` is because you want the terminating character to be `'\0'` in this line

```
if (errno != 0 || *p != '\0' || conv > INT_MAX)
```

But the text `2015` in `2015-08-26` is terminated by the `'-'` character.

So I recommend changing the line to

```
if (errno != 0 || (*p != '\0' && *p != '-') || conv > INT_MAX)
```

There are other ways to tackle it: your code won't break the date into its parts. You can do that by using `strtok()` but that wasn't your question.